# Oracle geospatials tutorials?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, geospatial

I am very interested in applications of [geospatials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geospatial).

Is there is a good tutorial?

I am a beginner at SQL, can I work with geospatials through the .NET environment?

What should I download to use spatials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle documentation set is very good, and it includes [a Spatial Developer's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/toc.htm).

I have to say though that Spatial is pretty tough going, and if I were new to SQL it's not where I would choose to start.